# Cannot add SPP layer in CNN using Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to apply Spatial Pyramid Pooling before the Dense layer in a CNN.

I used Keras for implementation.

Tensorflow was used as a backend.

However, I got an error.

What's wrong with my code? Thank you.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <module>
    model.add(SpatialPyramidPooling(pooling_regions, input_shape=Input(shape = (None,None,None,3))))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\spp\SpatialPyramidPooling.py", line 33, in __init__
    super(SpatialPyramidPooling, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 311, in __init__
    batch_input_shape = (batch_size,) + tuple(kwargs['input_shape'])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 439, in __iter__
    "Tensor objects are not iterable when eager execution is not "
TypeError: Tensor objects are not iterable when eager execution is not enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.`

Here is the code:

```
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
from keras.models import Sequential
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np

model = Sequential()
model.add(SpatialPyramidPooling((1,2,4), Input(shape=(None, None, None, 3))))

class SpatialPyramidPooling(Layer):
    def __init__(self, pool_list, **kwargs):

        self.dim_ordering = K.image_dim_ordering()
        assert self.dim_ordering in {'tf', 'th'}, 'dim_ordering must be in {tf, th}'

        self.pool_list = pool_list

        self.num_outputs_per_channel = sum([i * i for i in pool_list])

        super(SpatialPyramidPooling, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, x, mask=None):

        input_shape = K.shape(x)
        print(input_shape)
        print(K.eval(input_shape))
        outputs = K.variable(value=np.random.random((3,4)))

        return outputs
```

Comment: Is this your whole code? getting `NameError: name 'SpatialPyramidPooling' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you should be using `input_shape=(None,None,None,3)` instead of `input_shape=Input(shape = (None,None,None,3))`

Also, you cannot use any function that demands the presence of data in the `call` method. You're using `K.shape` and `K.eval`, both will bring you errors in compilation.

If you need information about the input shape, you have to do it in the `def build(self, input_shape):` method.

Comment: It returns `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'spatial_pyramid_pooling_7_input' with dtype float and shape [?,?,?,?,3]
  [[Node: spatial_pyramid_pooling_7_input = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,?,?,?,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]`

Comment: Updated my answer.